# How to store API authentication password?

Tags: api, password, encryption

I am connecting a WP site to a service through the service API.

The API authentication of this service is done using the service account username and password, not API keys:

- You send a request to the service API and give the account username and password.
- You receive a token, valid for a number of hours, that allows you to make API requests.

The problem that I see is that the service account password will have to be stored in the WP database, to be used in the API authentication.

I can encrypt the password in the database, but in a way that allows it to be decrypted back to a simple text form, which is not secure.

I cannot encrypt it into a hash, store the hash and use that for the authentication.

What is the best practice for storing the password in this situation?

Comment: You need to use the unencrypted token to make your requests, so you can only store it in plain text or in a way that can be easily decrypted. There isn't a way around that, but it's normal and not really a problem. The security measures you need here are ensuring your database is secure, and that the tokens expire or can be revoked. If the API supports restricting IPs or domains that the token can be used from then that would be an additional layer of security.

Comment: @JacobPeattie The problem is that I have to store the account password, which is used to generate the token.

Comment: So not credentials unique to the API? Is this an Oauth API? Oauth usually has a process for refreshing tokens that doesn't use the username and password. In that case you'd perform the initial token request offline, or through a UI, and then the token refreshing would be done entirely with tokens.

Comment: The facet remains though, that if you need the password to make the request, you can't irreversibly encrypt it. Without knowing more about the API it's not possible to say what better options there are.

Comment: @JacobPeattie No, it is not an Oauth API. The authentication is done through supplying the service username and password. There are no better options on the API side.

Comment: Then you're out of luck, your only options are storing the credentials either as plain text or a reversible encryption. Proper hashing will render the password useless for your needs.

Comment: @JacobPeattie A reversible encryption is what I thought as well, just so that the password is not stored in plain text in the database. I asked the question to see if there is any other option I missed.